# Skip User Control Template Source Directory While Loading it in another Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a User Control with several images inside. I will set images sources from a main directory like `"Website\Pictures"`.

My User Control is located in a specific directory like this: `"Website\UControls"` (Template Source Directory)

I'm trying to Load my user control inside a div in another page. Everything will work OK but images sources. I will see user control's Template Source Directory at the beginning of every image and it cause to have broken links.

For example an image source should be like this: `"../Pictures/1.png"`, but I will have this: `"../UControls/Pictures/1.png"` where `"UControls"` is Template Source Directory.

How can I avoid such treating?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ~ operator as a sign of the root your site.

See this answer as an example
[getting base url of web site's root (absolute/relative url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540021/getting-base-url-of-web-sites-root-absolute-relative-url/2782306#2782306)

---

Seems my original answer is irrelevant to the problem.
Please try with leading slash as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx in the part

> `<img src="/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />`
>
> If the URL of your Web site is http://www.contoso.com, the path would resolve to the following:
>   `http://www.contoso.com/Images/SampleImage.jpg`

Comment: I know this, everything will be OK. but after loading User Control inside another control, it will automatically add its Template Source Directory into images' urls